# Need to fix problem import local file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-import

i can't fix this problem, [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder02' ] python3, using virtual environment (anaconda) - vscode
i cant import local file

```
from folder02.file02 import file02
```

Comment: Is this an intellisense problem?  Or the code won't run?

Comment: Is this an intellisense problem -- My problem is file doesn't know about its neighbouring files in the rest of the project

Answer (score 0):

You are running a file inside your project. The file doesn’t know about it’s neighbouring files in the rest of the project. You need to run python with the ‘-m’ flag.

For example if the file you want to run is inside ‘folder1/file1.py’

Run with ‘python -m folder1.file1’

Comment: Exactly this is a safe problem, your method was not working !!! Is there another way - & thank you my friend

Comment: Please clarify the structure of your project